# wordpress plugin shows an error upon activation

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

When I activate custom plugin in Wordpress it shows this error:

> The plugin generated 476 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation.
>
> If you notice headers already sent messages, problems with
>   syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this
>   plugin.

. And the plugin is working fine but Wordpress frontend footer is missing.

Comment: Unfortunately , a lot of the wordpress plugins in the wild are amateurish , badly written, highly conflicted,  and have very low standard . If you are a bit of a coder, fix it yourself. if not - either contact the plugin author , or find another plugin to do the same job for you.

Comment: Seems that you should check for support on the plugin support section or on a specialized Wordpress forum. Remember to give as many details as you can, like version of the plugin, version of WP, screenshot of a page with the problem, exact error message, etc.